OpenCV- AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
I'm working with a facial recognition based attendance system, and I'm getting the following error:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\scoop\apps\python\current\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\499\499b\First\train.py", line 57, in train_classifier
    clf= cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
         ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

The line of code that is giving the rise to this error is as follows:-
clf= cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

I'm using python version-3.11.5, and cv2 version- 4.8.1.
I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the modules, but nothing seems to work. For example-
pip install opencv-contrib-python
python -m pip install --user opencv-contrib-python

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Okay, so the cv2 module does not have anything named face.  So the question is, why did you EXPECT that?  Where did you get that line of code?  Did you copy it from some example?

@JohnGordon yes I was following a tutorial on YouTube. So what's the solution to this?

@furas I have added the full error message now.

maybe you have two Pythons installed and you install opencv-contrib-python in one Python but you run code in other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. Run print( os.executable ) to get /full/path/to/python and use it to install modules /full/path/to/python -m pip install ... for correct Python

Edit the question and add the output of this command pip show opencv-contrib-python and the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)
